# in a W10 Batch-file the 'if errorlevel' is not correctly evaluated when in a block

Tags: batch-file, block, errorlevel

I have problems with errorlevel always staying 0 when the IF is in a for block

I tried different syntax % ! etc

```
@Echo Off
rem no correct evaluation of IF ERRORLEVEL (syntax % or !)
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where^
 "Extension='lnk' And Name Like '%AppData:\=\\%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent\\%%'"^
 Get Target /Format:"MOF" 2^>Nul')Do For %%B In (odt pdf txt doc docx wpd wps csv swd vor uot uof pdb psw xls xlsx xlm wk1 wks 123 dif rtf sdc vor dbf slkppt pps pptx 
)Do If /I "%%~xA"==".%%B" If Exist "%%A" (
Echo(%%A
MailAlert -s "my PC MEDION" -r first.last@yahoo.be -b "recente" -a "%%A"

IF '!errorlevel!'=='0' (
    rem the IF is not executed ; neither with '%errorlevel%'=='0'
    rem   '%errorlevel%'=='0'   was tested succesfully  outside the for block !!
    echo isSend: %%A
    rem shortcut to be deleted 
) ELSE (
    ECHO "An error was found w/ error code of: %ERRORLEVEL%"
        rem  !! errorlevel was never correct (is always 0) although the if function was correctly evaluated (as beeiing not 0) but only outside the 'for' block !!! 
    ECHO "in file:%%A" 
    rem shortcut not to be deleted 
) 

)
```

outside the for block I tested the code by sending an attached file which was opened and this provoked an error (produced by mailalert) which was well detected by if '%errorlevel%== ….. Another file which was not opened was effectively send by mailalert and provoked  errorlevel 0.

Comment: Using `delayedexpansion`, the run-time value of a variable is accessed by `!var!`. `%var%` is always the parse-time value. Hence ` ECHO "An error was found w/ error code of: %ERRORLEVEL%"` will display the value of `errorlevel` at parse-time, not as it is established by `mailalert`. Use `!errorlevel!` to display the value as it has changed. BTW `if errorlevel 1 (echo !errorlevel! - 1 or more ) else (echo errorlevel 0)` should work in this position.

Comment: I heve used !errorlevel! as you can see in the code. It doesn't function when used in the for block. I do not understand how to apply  " if errorlevel 1 (echo !errorlevel! - 1 or more ) else (echo errorlevel 0)". here you don't use the !..!; is the hyphen a hyphen or arrytmetic? Normally output from mailalert is 0 if it succeeded...

Comment: Does mailalert run in a separate cmd process perhaps losing it's errorlevel to the closed process and you receiving the errorlevel resulting from cmd closing?

Comment: Oh, and BTW, I would suggest with that many extensions, that you'd be better off piping the `WMIC` result into `FindStr` using them either named or from a list, then removing the nested `For` loop; it would certainly speed things up.

Comment: I would also recommend not enabling delayed expansion until you need to, and ending it when no longer necessary.

Comment: I saw that you correctly used `!errorlevel!` in your `if` statement, but I also observed that you used `ECHO "An error was found w/ error code of: %ERRORLEVEL%"` in the `else` section. I predict that were you to use `!errorlevel!` here as well, then the `errorlevel` returned by `mailalert` would be reported rather than the value as it stood when the `for` was parsed. Consequently, you would then have the tols to decode whatever `mailalert` is complaining about.

Comment: @magoo: remains 0 after using !..!

Comment: @compo: errorlevel check in the IF is correct when used outside the for block; on the other hand when I try to echo it, there too it is 0.... a mystery for me

Comment: @patpin, did you see my initial comment, can you confirm whether mail alert opens and runs in a separate cmd.exe instance? Have you considered running it with `Start`? you could even try that with and without its `/B` option!

Comment: @patpin Your code echoes `%errorlevel%`, not `!errorlevel!`. `%errorlevel%` is evaluated when the entire `for` loop code is parsed. When the `for` loop code executes, you get `0` as it is already has expanded to literal `0` and remains literal `0`. `!errorlevel!` is evaluated at code execution and can change value on each use. The comparisons may work ok as to the use of `!`, though the single quotes are not good to use to enclose values.

Comment: Please try this and report results : Directly after the `setlocal` line, add `SET "errorlevel="` then insert `ECHO ERRORLEVEL=!errorlevel!` directly after the `mailalert` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Following 4 lines are the powershell command
set pscommand=^&{^
$sh= New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;^
ForEach ($lnk in Get-ChildItem '!AppData!\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.lnk'^) {^
ForEach ($target in $sh.CreateShortcut($lnk^).TargetPath^) {Write-Host $lnk'^|'$target}}}

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=|" %%A in ('powershell -noprofile -command "!pscommand!"') do (
    rem Disable delayed expansion as can remove exclaimation marks in paths.
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%C In (
        odt pdf txt doc docx wpd wps csv swd vor
        uot uof pdb psw xls xlsx xlm wk1 wks 123
        dif rtf sdc vor dbf slkppt pps pptx
    ) do (
        if /i "%%~xB" == ".%%~C" if exist "%%~B" (
            echo(Link:   "%%~A"& echo(Target: "%%~B"

            rem Attach .lnk file to mail
            MailAlert -s "my PC MEDION" -r first.last@yahoo.be -b "recente" -a "%%~A"

            if errorlevel 1 (
                rem Shortcut not to be deleted

                rem Backup errorlevel using call set to resolve the doubled percent signs.
                call set "error_level=%%errorlevel%%"

                rem Enable delayed expansion to echo the backup of errorlevel
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                echo An error was found w/ error code of: !error_level!
                endlocal

                echo inFile: "%%~B"
            ) else (
                rem Shortcut to be deleted
                echo del "%%~A"

                echo isSend: "%%~B"
            )
            echo(
        )
    )

    endlocal
)
```

This shows how to backup the `errorlevel` to another
variable, and use it after setting `setlocal` as
`setlocal` can set the `errorlevel`.

Unless `echo` of the `errorlevel` is important,
I would omit it as it is the only named variable
that needs expansion within the `for` loop.
Without it, the need for expansion requiring
enabling delayed expansion, or `call set`, or
`call echo` would not be required. The code
shows just 1 variation for the `echo` of the
`errorlevel`.

Paths may have exclaimation marks so enabling delayed
expansion while the paths are expanded as text, can
make the exclaimation marks in the path disappear,
thus making affected paths invalid. To avoid this,
enable and disable delayed expansion as needed.

I found `wmic` quite slow as it does system wide
searches and gave no results with your code, so
am using `powershell` to read the targets from
the `.lnk` files.
If suitable, it is a replacement to `wmic`.

The `for` variables:

- `%%A` is the link path
- `%%B` is the target path
- `%%C` is the extensions to compare to the target path extensions

View `if /?` for information about handling `errorlevel`.
Note the `if errorlevel 1` check that requires no
variable expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have no experience at all with powershell. Should I run this code from a command windows after putting it in a  .bat file?

Comment: It will work from a command window from a .bat file. There is no `pause` at the end so if you click on it, you may miss the event. The `del` is only echoed so it is quite safe, except the `MailAlert` may run.

Comment: Michael_heath. I have tried that code in a bat file and it does only echo's its commands to the screen (onece per file in the map). No mails are send. Nor errorlevel set; not one filename shown on the screen.

Comment: If no `.lnk` targets match the extension types, nothing will be shown nor emails sent. Try an `echo(%%A` right before the `for %%C In (` to see if you get the .lnk paths echoed. I get four `.lnks` echoed ready for deletion.

Comment: as you can see I added this:    echo(lookingAt%%A      after the setlocal. I see nothing, not even the      lookingAt    on the screen...

Comment: I have put the     ' echo(lookingAt%%A'    after the        ' ) do ('     then I get as result : for the '%%A':  'c:\Windows/System32'.     I have not altered anything else on yr code (besides the email address). As mentiond before the same echo above the 'for' produces nothing.

Comment: detail: ForEach ($lnk in Get-ChildItem '!AppData!\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\*.lnk'^)  remains the same!

Comment: `%%A` returning `c:\Windows/System32` for you is very odd. As you mentioned environment, I tested Win7 and Win10. Perhaps Group Policy setting or something other is an obstacle. Looking for a way to reproduce is like looking for a needle in a haystack for me. Sorry, I do not know why you get those results.

Comment: Thanks for all input. I am learning powershell and am working on that project.